# Cannot find namespace 'xxx'.ts(2503)

Tags: typescript

`apis/link.ts`:

```
export interface Link {
  id: string;
  text: string;
}

export function getLinks(): Link[] {
  return [{ id: '1', text: 'a' }];
}
```

`apis/index.ts`:

```
import * as link from './link';

export default {
  link,
};
```

`main.ts`:

```
import apis from './apis';

type Data = apis.link.Link;  // Cannot find namespace 'apis'.ts(2503)

function main() {
  const data: Data[] = apis.link.getLinks();
  console.log(data);
}
```

I want to use `apis.link` as some kind of namespace. When I try to import the `apis` module and use the `Link` interface defined in `apis/link.ts` file, TSC throws an error:

> Cannot find namespace 'apis'.ts(2503)

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "dom", "es2018.promise"],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

TypeScript version: `"typescript": "^4.1.3"`